# Convert Firestore Data into own Array format

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Until now, I stored the categories data in an array and displayed them.

```
var categories: [BusinessCategory] = [
    .init(id: "id1", name: "Doctor", image: "https://icon.url"),
    .init(id: "id2", name: "Restaurant", image: "https://icon.url"),
    .init(id: "id4", name: "Citizen Service", image: "https://icon.url"),
    .init(id: "id5", name: "Barber Shop", image: "https://icon.url"),
    .init(id: "id6", name: "Corona-Test", image: "https://icon.url")
]
```

I would like to move this into a Database by using Firestore. After storing the categories in different documents, the format is of course different when using `getDocuments()`

```
func getAllCategories(){
    database.collection("categories").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.data())")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The results of the `getDocuments()` call is:

```
["image": https://icon.url, "name": Restaurant, "id": 2]
["image": https://icon.url, "name": Citizen Service, "id": 3]
["image": https://icon.url, "name": Doctor, "id": 1]
["image": https://icon.url, "name": Corona-Test, "id": 5]
["image": https://icon.url, "name": Barber Shop, "id": 4]
```

Any ideas on how to do it the best way? I need to transform all categories

```
["image": https://icon.url, "name": Doctor, "id": 1]
```

into

```
.init(id: "id1", name: "Doctor", image: "https://icon.url"),
```

Comment: This `.init(id:` appears to be a function call which would indicate your array is populated with dynamic data using that function. You can't directly store it in that way. But your document can certainly have fields for that data; id, name and image. Have your reviewed [Adding Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) and then [Reading Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) from Firestore using those fields? (hint: one option is for each array element would/could be a separate document in a collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can create a struct called `BusinessCategories` for storing each of the category item, within your project. You will need to use `Codable` Protocols and use `setData` function (write function) to create necessary documents in the Firestore.

```
struct BusinessCategories: Codable, Identificable {

var id: String
var name: String
var image: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
case id
case name
case image
}

}
```

2. After storing data model `BusinessCategories` in the Firestore, you can retrieve them via `getDocuments` or `snapshotlisteners` whichever you prefer.
3. Once you retrieve/read the `BusinessCategories` document From Firestore, you can decode (use for-loop to convert document into the struct you already created) the Firestore data into the struct which you already created beforehand.

So far, this is the cleanest and the usual way to perform the task you desired. you may also refer to this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-yQeAf3bLE

Otherwise, if you really want to clump the BusinessCategories into an array. You will keep encountering the problem you are currently facing and you will need (difficult, I think) customization to convert the data, definitely an uphill task.